# Removing all SMTP addresses but one

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

My Exchange 2010 users have numerous smtp addresses and I would like to remove all but two of them. Trying the following with no luck:

```
get-mailbox test_2 | foreach { $a = $_.emailaddresses; $b = $_.emailaddresses; foreach($e in $a) { if (($e.tostring() -match "donotdelete") -and ($e.tostring() -notmatch "donotdelete2")) { $b -= $e; } } ; $_ | set-mailbox -emailaddresses $b }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$mbx = get-mailbox test_2 
$emailAddresses = $mbx.emailaddresses | where { "put your your filter code here  }
set-mailbox $mbx -emailaddresses $emailAddresses
```